# How can I make a header like this in css and html

Tags: html, css, header, profile, image

I want it to have a profile picture on the left side with a black border on the right side. I want another picture on the left side with a border on the left side and I want my logo in the middle. The pictures are 82px by 82px and the whole header is 100% by 82px. Could you write this for me in html and css?

Here a pic of it that I want it to look like
http://s1167.photobucket.com/user/unlivedgears/media/image-10.jpg.html

Comment: the picture is just amazing +1

Comment: @Jawad +1 for that reason ?? o.O

Comment: @SachinG Admit it, the picture is amazing!

Comment: @user2019515 Indeed. :)

Comment: @SachinG: just look at the picture mate. There goes your wire framing out the window.

Comment: Forget html, the whole internet should be designed on graph paper. That's the new facebook right there.

Comment: you know the OP maybe like 10 years old. It can be forgiven. Just love the picture.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="img l"></div>
    <div class="img r"></div>
    <div class="img logo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
}

.img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}

div.l{
    float:left;
    border-right:5px solid black;
}

div.r{
    float:right;
    border-left:5px solid black;
}

div.logo{
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sDVGc/

Comment: @Jawad What's so funny? :o

Comment: the picture man, the picture!

Comment: I think it's the fact that you wrote all of the OP's code for him.

Comment: @JimHurley: Nop. I am myself guilty of that. It's the picture, the whole picture and nothing but the picture!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="header">
 <div id="profile_picture">
  <img src="profile_picture.jpeg" alt="Profile Picture" height="82" width="82" /> 
 </div>
 <div id="another_picture">
  <img src="another_picture.jpeg" alt="Another Picture" height="82" width="82" />
 <div>
 <div id="logo">
  <img src="logo.jpeg" alt="Logo" height="X" width="Y" />
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

div#header
{
height: 82px;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}

div#profile_picture
{
float: left;
border-right: Xpx;
}

div#another_picture
{
float: left;
border-left: Xpx;
}

div#logo
{
float: right;
width: Xpx;
height: Xpx;
}
```

Comment: no up votes please. The picture made me do it.